# Checkbox Issue on Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, spannablestring, android-spannable

I have a checkbox with link in its text .

When ever I checked the checkbox with touch , it automatically clicks the link also which is present in its text .
I have used spannable text for making part of text as  link .
This is causing issue .

How can I resolve it .

Comment: Can you share the code and the UI?

Comment: What behavior do you actually want? To be able to toggle the checkbox when touching it but to open the link only when touching the text? They by default act together as a single button since a checkbox by itself is a frustratingly small target to tap.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplest method. You can create a new view whose size equal the checkbox and place it over the checkbox. What's more, the view that you have just created is attached by a click listner in which you set the checkbox's state manually to trigger the visual change of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the xml layout below for checkbox with text which has a link in the string file. You can set the link dynamically as well.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_with_link"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text_with_link_string" />
```

```
<string name="text_with_link_string">I agree to the <a href="https://example.com/">terms and conditions</a></string>
```

If you need the layout in compose. I can add it as well. Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Isn't there a way to not disable checkbox click on link in text when we checked on checkbox

Comment: Cannot get your point.
Do you want to toggle the checkbox on the text click?